# How to show live JSON data on server

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping. I can do scrape data now easily. Now, I want to show some live **flight data** on my website. It is `JSON` data. How can I do that, I don't need a tutorial, I just what to know what should I use to do this?.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "flight data on my website". Do you have any kind of webservice where your website is inside? Do you want a webscraper which automatically saves data inside your website?

Comment: @dcariotti  Yes. I have the scaper, I am not clear on how the scraped live data is meant to be sent to a website. The site is displaying data via a request to a url which ends in `php`. Do I need to `post requests` to that URL. Basically how is live data streamed to a website. Not my own let's say but someone asks me to send the data to their website. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways for your problem:

1. make a POST request to your website and save data
2. use a publish/subscribe

The real answer is: it depends from your website, because if you want to use `Point 1.` you have to write, inside your website, an endpoint to requests form data and save the data inside a database.

Let's assume you use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library to make HTTP requests to an endpoint named `https://example.com/v1/flight_data` and you've got a Flask webapp under your website:

```py
# scraper
requests.post("https://example.com/v1/flight_data", data=<dictionary_with_data>)

# webapp
@app.route("v1/flight_data")
def post_flight_data():
    data = request.json
    # manipulate and save these data
```

---

`Point 2.` could be created with Redis, read more about it [here](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub).

I suggest you to use Redis if you don't want to store data inside a "normal" database like Postgres or MySQL but check for a moment and delete them after very short time.

Comment: I got some details. I need to scrape it, host it on my own server and then the other site gets it from there. So, I am assuming, I share the scraped data to Flask? and then do I create an API or something for them to scrape off of my website?..This is the part I am not getting

Comment: Nah, split it in two project: scraper will be always active right? The scraper sends data to Flask app. The webapp is always ready to response.